# Drag and drop a file then POST to a URL using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have figured out the drag and drop part but how would I then upload and POST the file to a URL with set parameters?

If I had a form I would just

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  action="url">  
 <input type="?" name="?"/>  
 <input type="?" name ="?" value="?"/>  
 </form>
```

How would I do above using the HTML5 drag and drop API???

Comment: I don't understand at all what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: I would like to drag and and drop an image into the browser and have it upload to a website

Comment: I would like to POST and set parameters like a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this MDC tutorial is what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications

It discusses the drag/drop operation up to uploading the file with the new local file support.

Comment: @Kenshi: Hopefully that's enough, but it would be important to say that I don't think you can add any data from the drop to a fileinput -- you would have to upload that through an AJAX request.